# How to display AnyBadge on GitHub README?

Tags: github, eslint, github-actions, pylint, badge

I'm using **AnyBadge**
https://github.com/jongracecox/anybadge with **GitHub** Action.
But I cannot find a way to show the badge on README and cannot find any doc written in this repo.

I tried to save it in Artifacts. However, it's a zip file and without url, so I don't know how to show it on README.

1. Does anyone know how to display it on README?
2. Any doc regarding the use with ESLint?

Thanks!

Note: Our repo is **private**(organiztion)

Comment: Are you trying to generate the **github action workflow status badge** which uses AnyBadge? Or is it something else?

Comment: If it's the github action workflow status badge, [here is a good reference about it](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/adding-a-workflow-status-badge)

Comment: I want to add other badges like Pylint result, code coverage or any result producing in my workflow.etc. using AnyBadge.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/anuraghazra/github-readme-stats
you can check this and just you have to copy some commands in your readme.MD file which is basically a special type of repository we use to show only introduction and details like these.

For Readme. MD
https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/customizing-your-profile/managing-your-profile-readme

https://github.com/aleen42/badges

Comment: thanks, I forgot to note that my repo is private(in our company's), so I think the links you provided are for public.

Comment: yes public your repo so it will be visible to everyone
thankyou.